# Python Traceback Error

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

Unable to create a response with this api.I am unable to call the function locu_search('new york'). I get the following error shown below. I am using Komodo as my IDE, this started when I created a new python shell.

```
import urllib2
import json

local_api = '0d5897aae41eeafbd62ad0815af15cc42b2ed7c0'

def locu_search(query):
api_key = local_api
url = 'https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?api_key=' + api_key
locality = query.replace('','%20')
final_url = url + "&locality=" + locality + "&category=restaurant"
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(final_url)
data = json.load(json_obj)

for item in data['objects']:
    print item['name'],item['phone']

  locu_search('new york')
```

The error is listed below:

```
  **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 0, in <module>
  File "<console>", line 0, in locu_search
  File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 437, in open
 response = meth(req, response)
 File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
 File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 475, in error
 return self._call_chain(*args)
 File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
 result = func(*args)
 File "c:\python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
 raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
 HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: BAD_REQUEST**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

400 Bad Request should give you a headsup about the problem , this is basically due to a malformed request and I strongly suspect the culprit is in th line `url = 'https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?api_key=' + api_key` , check if `api_key` token is invalid or no longer valid.